# Per-user faketime in Linux

Tags: linux, time

I already know about faketime and datefudge, but is there a way to set this up transparently for any process that's being run as a certain user (identified by a specific UID)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the entire source code to Linux, you *can* set this up
exactly as you want, but you'll have to modify the system kernel and
rebuild it to make it so.  It isn't *easy* to set this up based on a UID.

If you only want to arrange that a logged in user has this property for
most commands they execute, give them a login shell that uses `faketime`
to set the environment variable and then call their real shell.
You can get a taste for how this looks by doing it interactively:

```
$ date
Mon Oct 14 14:02:05 EDT 2013
$ faketime yesterday bash
$ date
Sun Oct 13 14:02:10 EDT 2013
$ exit
$ date
Mon Oct 14 14:02:15 EDT 2013
```

A special login shell should also work for `cron` jobs that use the user's login shell.

Of course this fakery fails for any program that sets or ignores its
own `$LD_PRELOAD` information:

```
$ faketime yesterday bash
$ date
Sun Oct 13 14:02:20 EDT 2013
$ env -i /bin/date
Mon Oct 14 14:02:25 EDT 2013
```